# Button Content not always showing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Based on the below xaml, does anybody know why if I create 2 (or more) buttons (with implicit styles), only 1 of them actually displays the content, however all display the blue border.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">

  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1">
          <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>

  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>

  <Setter Property="Content">
    <Setter.Value>
      <Grid Background="Firebrick"/>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>

</Style>
```

Checking the code behind, all 3 buttons have the exact same content, yet it is only ever displayed on 1 of them

```
if (a.Style == b.Style && a.Style == c.Style)
{
    if (a.Content == b.Content && a.Content == c.Content)
    {
        // comes in here!
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: all 3 buttons have the exact same content, but UIElement cannot belong to more than one parent and therefore displayed in last of button. consider making Grid a part of Template

Comment: Take a look at the fourth bullet in the Remarks section of the [ContentPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN: *If Content is a UIElement object, the UIElement is displayed. If the UIElement already has a parent, an exception occurs*. However, apparently no exception occurs, or it is caught internally.

Comment: Very frustrating, thought this might have been the issue but confused me as no exception is raised.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a Button's content in style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250709/set-a-buttons-content-in-style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as mentioned by Clemens and ASh is the Grid in the Content cannot have more than 1 parent.

The workaround is to use a DataTemplate and set the element's ContentTemplate as the DataTemplate (as described in the thread below).

[Set a Button's content in style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250709/set-a-buttons-content-in-style)

Answer (score 0):

I already faced this issue with button images. This is linked to your style where you defined the `Content` property and not the `Template` property. By setting the `Content` property you don't define a reference to something nor you ask WPF to create a new object for every item, meaning only the last element rendered with the style will have is `Content` set.

So what you want to do is either, set the `ContentTemplate` property if you planned to set a content to every buttons. Or set the `Template` property if you actually only want to change the aspect of the `Button`.

For example with the Template property:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>

<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />

<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid Background="Firebrick" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```